# jQuery smooth div scroll not scrolling dynamically created paragraph tags

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a stock ticker and I'm trying to use the [Smooth Div Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/) plugin but I can't get it to work with dynamically created paragraph tags. Rather than creating a scrolling, horizontal list, it just dumps the P tags onto the page vertically. If the paragraphs tags are added statically, they are positioned and scroll correctly. When I compare a static version to this dynamic version in Firebug, the html looks the same so I'm guessing it's a CSS issue, but I'm not having any luck.

**EDIT:** Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/RZBUJ/1/)

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Here's the code

```
$(window).load(function () {
        var $divScrollableArea = $(".scrollableArea");
        var $stocks = new Array("GOLD", "SSRI", "PTM", "PAL", "USD", "SH", "DJI");

        $.each($stocks, function (index, item) {
            var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22" + item + "%22)%0A%09%09&&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
            $(function () {
                var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
                    $divScrollableArea.append("<p>" + item + "<br /><span class='left'>" + json.query.results.quote.BidRealtime + 
                        "</span><span class='right'>" + json.query.results.quote.Change_PercentChange + "</span></p>");
                })
                .success(function () { BuildScroll(); });
            });
        });
        function BuildScroll() {
            $("div#scrollingText").smoothDivScroll({
                autoScroll: "always",
                autoScrollDirection: "endlessloopright",
                autoScrollStep: 1,
                autoScrollInterval: 15
            });
        }
    });


<style type="text/css">
    .stock
    {
        font: bold .8em Verdana;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .innerStock
    {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .left
    {
        font: normal .7em Verdana;
        text-align: left;
        width: 30%;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
    .right
    {
        font: normal .7em Verdana;
        text-align: right;
        color: red;
    }
    #scrollingText
    {
        width: 100px;
        height: 35px;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        position: relative;
        padding: 2px 0px;
    }

    #scrollingText div.scrollableArea p
    {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding-right: 7px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        font-family: Courier, Arial, Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width:300px;
    }
</style>

<div id="scrollingText">
    <div class="scrollWrapper">
        <div class="scrollableArea">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help tremendously if you could set-up a fiddle at http://http://jsfiddle.net/ for something like that.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that... long day. I added a link

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is a CSS problem.

More specifically it is the width of `#scrollingText` (100px) that causes the line-breaks. If you remove this attribute, your paragraphs will be floated (it would pay to reduce the width of the paragraphs too).

If you want to keep the size of `#scrollingText` fixed, you will need to define styles for `div.scrollWrapper` like so:

```
div.scrollWrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
}
```

Just make sure that the width is larger than the sum of all widths of the contained paragraphs.
I have updated your fiddle (not I also adjusted the width of the paragraphs): http://jsfiddle.net/RZBUJ/2/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I removed the width from #scrollingText but it's still not scrolling, and the last item is still breaking to the next line.

Comment: With regards to the last item still breaking to the next line... you have to ensure that the scrollWrapper width accomodates all floated elements. If it is even 1 pixel narrower than the sum width of the floated elements, the last one will be sitting behind a line break.

Comment: As for the smoothDivScroll not working... I must admit that I don't know where to start. The Javascript code is riddled with errors, e.g. to my knowledge there is no `.success()` function, if there were it would be called multiple times as it is enclosed by the $.each function. So perhaps it's best to go back to the drawing board, rewrite your function. Perhaps start with a working scroller and then, step by step, add your ajax data population.

Answer (score 0):

change your css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .stock
    {
        font: bold .8em Verdana;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .innerStock
    {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .left
    {
        font: normal .7em Verdana;
        text-align: left;
        width: 30%;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
    .right
    {
        font: normal .7em Verdana;
        text-align: right;
        color: red;
    }
    #scrollingText
    {
        width: 400px;
        height: 80px;
        border: solid 1px #ccc;
        position: relative;
        padding: 2px 0px;
        overflow:auto;
    }

    #scrollingText div.scrollableArea p
    {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding-right: 7px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        font-family: Courier, Arial, Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #000;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width:300px;
    }
</style>
```